# path syntax in python on windows for imports

Tags: python-3.x

I have structured my python project on Windows so that `Juypter` notebooks are in there own folder.

The paths are like this:

```
\src\tracker\timer.py
\notebooks\notebook_files.nypyb
```

My import statement in the `notebook_file` used to look like:

```
from timer import Timer
```

But now this fails with import could not be resolved.

I have tried various combinations to pass the full path (up one folder and down /src/tracker)

```
from ../src/tracker.timer import Timer
from ..src/tracker.timer import Timer
```

But neither of these work. How can I get the import to be resolved?

Comment: Can you show us your directory structure?

Comment: Sorry I - I gave the path to the notebook and the path to the timer.py that I want to import - did you need something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import statements do not refer to directory paths, but *module* paths. If you add `\src` to your PYTHONPATH (or `sys.path`) you can `from tracker.timer import Timer` (assuming, that is, that `\src\tracker\__init__.py` exists so `tracker` is a valid package)

Comment: @RayBond notably the reason that this worked before you moved the notebook is that the current directory is always on the PYTHONPATH :)